# How do I setup Entity Framework Core 2.1 with Sqlite? - Connecting Database to My Solution

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, entity-framework-core

I am not an expert on this technology yet, so I guess for most this is a very basic question... But I don't really know how to use DBContext and how can I really connect my database, to the cross-platform solution file... and which nuget packages should I use?... where do I reference it?... what classes should I make and what codes do I put in it?... These questions, that I don't even know how to apply on my solution, I hope it doesn't bother you guys...

My goal is to make a datagrid using xaml grid, binded with sqlite database using entity framework core 2.1...

If you can answer my question in a step-by-step guide that would be really helpful for me...

*How can I setup the Entity Framework Core 2.1 using the database that I created from sqlite?

```
    * My Database Location & Name: C:\sqlite\demo.db
    * My Target Framework: .Net Standard 2.0
    * My Visual Studio Version: 15.7.2
    * For Android, IOS, & UWP
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dotnet` command line tool:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=demo.db;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir DataFolder -c "context name"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db